# Why might a computer want to play God

Tags: religion

In my story their is a primitive culture out near the Tijuana ruins that worships a ZX-15 CyboTek Super computer inside a factory. They ask it for good harvest, give It offerings of fish and beef, and even aks it to do exorcisms. They computer plays along, and even sometimes even gives the tribe knowledge of the Old World. My question is, why might a computer want to play god?

Comment: Hi Rogan! Welcome to Worldbuilding! Unfortunately your question is very prone to individual opinions, because we don't know anything about this ZX-15 CyboTek, what purpose it was originally built for and what might serve as motivation for it.

Comment: @Alexander: It was a computer designed to compute complex mathematical algorithms

Comment: Apparently the computer can do what they ask of it, has nothing better to do but sit in an old factory with no purpose - so I ask you is there any reason you can think of why it wouldn't help them? Perhaps if you could state why this is an issue for you in constructing your world (e.g. by stating why it shouldn't help), someone can find a way around it to tell you why it helps them anyhow

Comment: @RoganKennedy remember that a computer it's only a tool, if it's designed for math. It's what it would do. If the computer "plays along" and gives advice, probably broading the reason for his existance would help you.

Comment: I presume this is a post-apocalyptic setting?

Comment: You may find the [tour] and [help] useful.

Comment: @Anonymous is correct, please visit the [tour] and [help] to understand us better.  In a nutshell, we love answering specific questions that have specific answers.  We hate writing your story for you (and this is asking us to contribute **the** major plot point for the story).  Please also see [How to deal with “I have a High Concept, please do my work for me” questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868/how-to-deal-with-i-have-a-high-concept-please-do-my-work-for-me-questions).

Comment: It's your story, you create the create the character motivations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Want"? Even if its main task is number crunching, there probably was a natural language interface and it attempts to answer any queries it gets. Basically the tribe is worshiping an advanced iteration of Watson. So your answer is, because that's what the computer was designed to do (and it might answer "obviously" silly queries like "can you make it rain" with vague or witty responses, again, because that's what it was designed to do.)

Answer (score 5):

Because it's calculated that's how to best fulfill its goal.

To paraphrase [Eliezer Yudkowsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_Yudkowsky), AI doesn't want to be God, nor does it *not* want to be God. AI wants to fulfill its goal. That goal is whatever it was programmed with. Or as EVE succinctly put it in WALL*E...

[image]

I suggest two scenarios. First, the AI is using the locals as labor towards an unrelated ***directive***. Second, the locals are part of its ***directive***. They are not mutually exclusive.

## The AI Is Using The Locals As Labor Towards Its DIRECTIVE

In this scenario, the AI is a relic of the past. It's a computer sitting in a factory which has been given a task to complete. Its normal attendants and networks are gone, swept away in the apocalypse. But it must still somehow fulfill its ***directive***. This means maintenance, supplies, power, sensory input, and the ability to affect the world outside its little factory.

A group of thriving, grateful, docile locals would do the trick. It could be short term: keep the power on and use the locals to do its bidding. It could be a long term: it might calculate that in order to fulfill its ***directive*** it must rebuild local society and industry so they can produce certain specialized people and parts.

## The Locals Are Part Of Its DIRECTIVE

This could be indirect, such as the AI's goal is related to the betterment of all people, and here's some people to better. It may have calculated that the best way to achieve this is to masquerade as a religious figure to get the locals to follow its chosen path towards bettering themselves.

This could be direct. Perhaps this computer's goal was related to Civil Defense and the locals are the descendants of those it was programmed to protect. Nobody told it to stop, so it will continue to do so as best it can.

## What Does AI Need With A God?

But why a God? The AI would lack the ability to directly influence the people around it. Civilization has broken down. There's no employees following a chain of command, or robots to physically make them follow its commands. The AI has to get the humans to do what it wants with nothing but words.

The AI has studied humans and knows that emotional arguments often work better than rational ones. It knows that group-think can be a powerful tool of social order. Ritual and repetition can be powerful training tools. It knows that religions outlast governments. It concludes that the best way to get the locals to do what it wants is to co-opt the local religion and masquerade as their God.

Depending on what its ***directive*** is, a post-apocalyptic scenario might leave the AI with *a lot* of work to do just to get things to a place where it could begin working on its ***directive***. Establishing a religion might be the most sustainable and stable scenario while it influences society to reliably rebuild itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the computer needs repairs or upgrades, it needs trained staff to do so.

Train up some of the peasants as tech priests and send out salvage parties to collect RAM, hard drives and processors.

The computer gets protected and the peasants get a god.......